# Under what circumstance System.Collections.ArrayList.Add throws IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: .net, collections, arraylist

We are experiencing weird bug at production environment we cannot debug nor inject logging code. I am trying to figure this up but following stack trace confuse me.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object value)
   at ...
```

[According to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=VS.90).aspx) `Add` method should only throw `NotSupportedException`.

I have no idea what's going on here. Do you?

Comment: Can you post somewhat complete stacktrace?

Comment: just guessing: the ArrayList is used on multithreading operations?

Comment: You may be able to confirm concurrency bug by inspecting other thread states in the debugger when the exception occurs.  Check if someone else is altering the container at that time.

Comment: at the end of the day it finally looks like concurrency issue.

Comment: You can tell it's a concurrency problem when the element count in the array is a power of 2 (e.g. 8, 16, 32, 64, etc.)

Comment: Yep. It was concurrency issue. Once concurrent `Add` call break the `ArrayList` any subsequent `Add` fail with `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It boils down to List not being thread safe. I have had IndexOutOfRangeException occuring when iterating over a list *after* adding items using multiple threads *without* synchronization. The code below could corrupt the items count and result in IndexOutOfRangeException while iterating the list subsequently,

```
List<TradeFillInfo> updatedFills = new List<TradeFillInfo>();
Parallel.ForEach (trades, (trade) =>
{
    TradeFillInfo fill = new TradeFillInfo();

    //do something

    updatedFills.Add(fill); //NOTE:Adding items without synchronization
});

foreach (var fill in updatedFills) //IndexOutOfRangeException here sometimes
{
    //do something
}
```

Synchronizing the Add() with a lock statement will fix the issue.

```
lock (updatedFills)
{
    updatedFills.Add(fill);
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) is thrown when "an attempt is made to access an element of an array with an index that is outside the bounds of the array."

Note that the `ArrayList` class is not thread-safe. It is possible that in multi-threaded scenarios, race-conditions will result in the `ArrayList` attempting to read/write to the backing array at indices that are outside its range.

Example: One thread reduces the size of the backing array (perhaps through a `TrimToSize` call) at the same time that another thread is adding to the collection. Now, if the backing array is at full capacity, the adding thread will attempt to expand its capacity (by allocating a new array) to accomodate the new element. The simultaneous `TrimToSize` call then reverses this effect. Then, by the time the adding thread attempts to write to the array, the index that it *thought* was available would no longer be, causing the exception to be thrown.

Fix: Use thread-safe constructs, as appropriate to *your* situation.

Answer (score 12):

That's almost certainly a concurrency issue... You probably have two threads that modify the collection at the same time, and the `ArrayList` class is not designed to support concurrent access. A race condition occurs, which sometimes leads one of the threads to attempt to write at a position outside the bounds of the array.

Try to protect all accesses to the collection using `lock` statements, or use a synchronized wrapper of the collection (using the `ArrayList.Synchronized` method)