# IndexOutOfRangeException and NullReferenceException in MVC 5 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For the project I am working on we use a controller called "MediaDepot". This controller handles all requests for files on the server such as images.

The datamodel checks if the user has access to the file via the session object. The controller gets the session as a readonly dictionary.

**Below a sample of our controller:**

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class MediaDepotController : AsyncController
{
    [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "Hash;Width;Height;ImageID")]
    public ActionResult Get(string Hash, int Width, int Height, int ImageID)
    {
        ActualRequest aRequest = new ActualRequest(Request, Response as HttpResponseWrapper, ControllerContext, HttpContext, Session);
        MediaDepotResult result = MediaDepot.MediaDepot.Instance.GetFilePathOfImageItem(aRequest, Hash, Width, Height, ImageID);

        var File = Server.MapPath(result.FilePath);
        return base.File(File, result.FileType);
    }
```

On the production server the session object will sometimes refuse to load throwing out IndexOutOfRangeException or NullReferenceException on all requests from the client with that session.

**Stack trace**

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>      System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object value) +38
>      System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseAdd(String name, Object value) +98
>      System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseSet(String name, Object value) +43
>      System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.set_Item(String name, Object value) +29
>      System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.set_Item(String name, Object value) +14
>      System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper.set_Item(String name, Object value) +17
>      System.Web.Mvc.SessionStateTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 values) +101
>      System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Save(ControllerContext controllerContext, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider) +102
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PossiblySaveTempData() +72
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651516
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

I know this is a concurrency issue with the session object in mvc but how can it be prevented? And is there a better solution to serve files to the end user without linking to the files directly?

Comment: For reference [Under what circumstance System.Collections.ArrayList.Add throws IndexOutOfRangeException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794171/under-what-circumstance-system-collections-arraylist-add-throws-indexoutofrangee)

Comment: Change the `Location` to `System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server`. Does that make a difference? It looks like that should work, but perhaps the location of `Client` is the reason for the error?

Comment: removing the line does or changing it does not make a diffrence, however i have found a workaround that seems to work. I added this override to the controller:`protected override void EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                base.EndExecute(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }`

Comment: Seems odd that you have to go to that length, but if it works, then cool :)