# ArrayList.Contains throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist

I have a very weird non deterministic issue with my website (ASP.NET, not MVC). 
When performing stress tests (not too heavy) I am occasionally getting IndexOutOfRangeException in places where this should not be happening. The thing is that the code throwing exception is in 3rd party library, but looking at it, it does not give me any hints - there's nothing weird going on, just checking content of the array using Contains method, no loops through array items using index.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.Contains(Object item)
   at ThirdPartyClass.ThirdPartyMehtodThatChecksArrays
```

I know what IndexOutOfRangeException means and spent a few hours on this with my experienced friend, but no luck. We saw a few articles about similar issues (ie. [Under what circumstance System.Collections.ArrayList.Add throws IndexOutOfRangeException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794171/under-what-circumstance-system-collections-arraylist-add-throws-indexoutofrangee))
but don't see concurency problems in this website - whole methods calling chain are regular classess and methods, no static methods or classes.

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that it is not caused by your code you should present the problem to the producer of the thirdy party library. We cannot help on this without code.

Comment: It's really only going to happen with concurrent access (i.e. on more than one thread).  If you're really sure you're not doing this then you'll have to try and reproduce in isolation and raise with the 3rd party. As above, there's very little you can expect as an answer without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Charles you are right, it was concurrent access issue. Thanks.