# Why does List<T>.Add throw an index out of range exception?

Tags: c#, .net

When I call `List<T>.Add(T)` it throws this exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at ConsoleApp5.Program.AddToList(Int32 seed)
```

I've also see this exception thrown by `Enumerable.Any` against the same list.

Comment: [Edit] your post and include a [mcve]

Comment: @Jonathan Allen is it possible to see the code?

Answer (score 15):

This can be caused by a race condition. If two or more threads modify the list at the same time, it can become corrupted. After that point, any future operations against the list will fail.

Here is a sample that will reproduce it.

```
    static List<int> TestList;
    const int ThreadCount = 10;
    const int IterationsA = 1000;

        static int count = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TestList = new List<int>();
                List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

                for (var x = 0; x < ThreadCount; x++)
                {
                    var t = new Thread(() => AddToList(x));
                    t.Start();
                    threads.Add(t);
                }

                foreach (var t in threads)
                    t.Join();

                var b = TestList.Any(i => i == 1);

                Console.WriteLine("Pass " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed after {count} attempts");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void AddToList(int seed)
    {
        try
        {
            var random = new Random(seed);

            for (var x = 0; x < IterationsA; x++)

            {
                TestList.Add(random.Next());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed after {count} attempts");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Note that it may happen on the first iteration or after thousands of iterations.

Comment: So, use a thread-safe collection instead of `List<T>`? It's explicitly said in the documentation that it is not thread-safe: ["It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List<T>, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation...."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#thread-safety)

Comment: You totally missed the point. I wrote this to help people who see this exception in production and don't understand what went wrong. If they already know there's a race condition, they wouldn't be searching for this question.

Comment: I get that, but this answer could at least show how to fix the issue, otherwise this is not an answer

Comment: _I wrote this to help people who see this exception in production and don't understand what went wrong_ or they could just find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794171/under-what-circumstance-system-collections-arraylist-add-throws-indexoutofrangee), or a number of other similar ones

Comment: Or indeed the [IndexOutOfRangeException docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) - _"Violating thread safety. Operations such as ... from different threads can throw an IndexOutOfRangeException if the object isn't accessed in a thread-safe way. This exception is typically intermittent because it relies on a race condition."_

Comment: @stuartd, I mean, if we told all posts here that "you should check the docs instead", then there should be no questions at all.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I don't really see your point. Pointing people to the documentation a) allows them to solve their own problem and b) shows the value of reading the documentation _before_ asking a question. It's not like SO is short of questions.